# How to select all records from multiple tables in MySQL even if no match in some tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables (Stores, Item & StoreInv) and I am trying to do a join that contains all records from Stores & Items even if there are no matching records in StoreInv.  Probably easiest to explain by an example:

Store table:

```
StoreId
-------
Store1
Store2
Store3
```

Item table:

```
ItemId
-------
A
B
C
```

StoreInv table (only contains records for Items with inventory at the store):

```
ItemId    StoreId    Qty 
-------   -------    ---
A         Store1      6
B         Store1      2
B         Store2      4
```

Desired output:

```
StoreId    ItemId   Qty 
-------    ------   ---
Store1     A         6
Store2     A         0 (or null)
Store3     A         0 (or null)
Store1     B         2
Store2     B         4
Store3     B         0 (or null)
Store1     C         0 (or null)
Store2     C         0 (or null)
Store3     C         0 (or null)
```

What I have tried:

```
SELECT str.StoreId, itm.ItemId, inv.Qty
FROM Item itm
LEFT JOIN StoreInv inv ON inv.ItemId = itm.ItemId
RIGHT JOIN Stores str on str.StoreId = inv.StoreId
```

Result (not what I want):

```
StoreId    ItemId   Qty 
-------    ------   ---
Store1     A         6
Store1     B         2
Store2     B         4
Store3     null      null
```

Comment: What you want is a cross-product of the Store and Items tables (to get all the rows you want), and left-join that with StoreInv (to fill the Qty column).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `CROSS JOIN` the `Stores` and `Inv` table to get all the possible combinations. Then `LEFT JOIN` the `StoreInv` table to get the quantities of each.

```
SELECT str.StoreId, itm.ItemId, IFNULL(inv.Qty, 0) Qty
FROM Item itm
CROSS JOIN Stores str
LEFT JOIN StoreInv inv ON inv.ItemId = itm.ItemId AND inv.StoreID = str.StoreID
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e1J88ACTN41K6pAhaYbxAs/0)